# get blank response in google talent solution api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-api-client, google-apis-explorer

I want to search all jobs with google jobs api.
Here is my code.

```
job_query = {
        "query": "Python",
    }
request_metadata = {
        'user_id': 'UNKNOWN',
        'session_id': 'UNKNOWN',
        'domain': "UNKNOWN",
    }
jobs = client.search_jobs(parent, request_metadata,
                              job_query=job_query,
                              enable_broadening=False,
                              disable_keyword_match=False,
                              page_size=20,
                              search_mode="JOB_SEARCH",
                              )
```

Do google jobs api only return jobs i've created?

Comment: Can I see the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Jobs API does not provide a database of jobs, you must [add jobs](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/quickstart-jobs-and-companies) to your project before the search will return them. This API is intended to allow you to build a jobs systems.

Google does also have jobs.google.com which allows you to search jobs [listed](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/job-posting) on other websites, however there is no API to retrieve this data.